# Host multiple websites using NGINX server in localhost (Ubuntu14.1)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, host

To host multiple website, I updated /etc/nginx/default file as below:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name test;
    root /var/www/test;
    client_max_body_size 3096M;
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js){
        expires max;
    }
}
```

After this I edited /etc/hosts file as:

```
IP address  localhost test;
```

Final step:

```
service nginx restart / service nginx reload
```

Access website using : http://test , but it is redirecting to localhost and displaying Ubuntu installation page.

Answer (score 1):

test virtual host is listening on port 8080, so you should access it using http://test:8080.